# Return TRUE or FALSE if a value in an specific row of COL A exists in COL D

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

I have a table like this:

| ColA | colB | ColC | colD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123. | eb-23 | ?? | 567. |
| 987 | 120. | ?? | 123. |
| 111 | 56a. | ?? |  |

`colA` and `colB` contains equal number of value where as `colD` contains different number of values (colD is not a subset of colA but they both have a few values in common)

Now, I want the `ColC` to display `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending if the value in `colA` in that specific ROW matches with any of the values in `colD`

Comment: `=COUNTIF(D:D,A1)>0`

Comment: Not sure , I got your question right, but what I understand is that you want to check if the values in ColA is available on ColD... you can use VLOOKUP to do it as below
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$D$2:$D$10,1,0))

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=COUNTIF(D:D;A#) > 0
```

**#**: number of the row

This function counts only the cells that meet a criteria, in this case set by the values in column A.

If the number returned by the function is superior to 0 it means there is a match and so Excel returns `TRUE`, in opposite case `FALSE`